# Why does my pip install flask-security keep downloading the wrong project code?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

Recently, flask-security had been breaking due to an upgrade to Flask-Login 0.3. the problem lies from a method definition to a property definition of is_active() and is_authenticated() to is_active and is_authenticated respectively. This change is breaking my Flask app for registering, logging in.

On this project url [Correct Flask-Security code](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security) I need this version because if you look at the `decorators.py` file the `is_authenticated()` method that previously broke is correctly changed to is_authenticated.

However, whenever I invode`pip install flask-security` I get a version that has the incorrect code. The version in my site-packages directory specifies 1.7.4 which should be the correct version. So why does this break.

I resolved this with `easy_install flask-security` but I'm confused as why pip install didn't work. Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just recommend using the older version of Flask-Login until Flask-Security updates their version on PyPi.  In your `requirements.txt` file just specify the old version.  For example your `requirements.txt` might look like:

```
flask
flask-login==0.2.11
flask-security
flask-wtf
```

Then you can install it with `pip install -r requirements.txt` and you should be good to go.

To explain a little further, even in 1.7.4 [the decorator code](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/1.7.4/flask_security/decorators.py#L59) here is treating `user.is_authenticated()` as a callable, not a boolean as it now is (in Flask-Login 0.3) and because Flask-Security is telling pip "Grab me the latest version of Flask-Login please!" pip's grabbing 0.3 and the problem appears.

If you instead look at the [code in the development branch here](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/decorators.py#L60) you can see it's been corrected to now treat it as a boolean, but that development version isn't stable/pushed to PyPi yet.

To reduce the problem in the future, you can see that in the development branch's `requirements.txt` they've now got Flask-Login specified as `Flask-Login>=0.3.0,<0.4` which makes the assumption that Flask-Login's developers aren't going to make any breaking changes during their minor revisions on the way to 0.4.

Comment: You're right. I forgot that PyPi is the official package repository for pip. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: And considering the Flask-Login folks aren't already using semantic versioning, it's hard to say that they won't make an API change again. I would suggest that Dan pin all of his dependencies (including transitive ones). Also, https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988.